# Anyone get direct esp-now to raspberry pi (or other linux wifi device) working?

Tags: pi-2, esp8266

It would be nice to be able to use raspberry wifi to receive ESP-NOW messages directly and eliminate another ESP-to-PI device to manage.

I think this is where @ Alexandr Zarubkin
was going but I don't have the "status" here to ask/comment on his post:
https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/802-11-action-frames-send-and-receive-in-software

Comment: Get the status and then post!

Answer (score 1):

We are making progress in the Linux-ESP project: https://hackaday.io/project/161896-linux-espnow

The code should compatible with a Raspberry Pi as it uses raw socket to send/receive packets. You will have to set your wireless interface in monitoring mode first.

Please report raspberry pi compatibility if you can test this.

Comment: Monitor mode is not supported by the wifi onboard chip of Raspberry Pi.